# how to trim existing stud width?

Tags: wood, studs

I want to recess something into the wall between the studs.   Problem is that it is approx. 1/4" longer than the gap between the studs.  Is there a way to shave off this small amount of the existing stud (i.e. the "2" (1.5") side for about 2' length

Comment: I'm having trouble picturing this, can you draw a picture or draw on a photo?

Comment: handheld circular saw or a hand plane or japanese pull saw

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have several options here, and you're going to be stuck with some limitations as to which method you use. You can use a reciprocating saw, but as it was pointed out by @JACK, there's the danger of being unable to control the saw and cuttin all the way through to the other side.

You can use a hammer and chisel, but here you'll be shaking the entire wall and potentially cause some superficial damage that can cause some severe headaches if you have to match texture and/or paint. The reciprocating saw can also run this risk.

@Chris Butler also suggested a circular saw, which can work, but you're teetering on a very narrow edge and will cause a fair amount of mess.

My preference is to use a multitool if you have one available. If you don't have one, they're pretty inexpensive and very handy. This would allow you to do a plunge cut and you can use the fat edge of a speed square to help ensure you're keep to your 1/8" or 1/4" depth (1/8" if trimming both studs or 1/4" if only trimming 1 stud. These are also great in tight places.

You can try a combination of a laminate router, sharp utility knife, or chisel, but I wouldn't recommend that. I only mention it to try and cover all bases I can think of.

In case you haven't seen or heard of the multitool, here's a picture of one.
[image: Bosch Multitool]

Comment: The multi-tool would be cleaner, and as @brehma suggested, you could take the 1/4" off one stub.  A multi-tool will take longer than a circular saw, but a lot safer.

Comment: Yea agreed, this is the best option. I have one of these and use it for all kinds of things! Don't know why I didn't think of it myself!

Answer (score 1):

I would tackle that with a reciprocating saw. You could do two 1.75" cuts or one 3.5" cut depending on how comfortable you are with the saw. Just make sure you don't cut through the opposite wall. Cut your 1/4" cuts two feet apart and then cut out the strip between them. Make sure there's no wiring going through the stud.

Comment: Personally I would have thought a reciprocating saw would make a find mess of a cut like that?

Comment: it's going to be hard to do a 1.75" cut on the 1.5" side of the board.

Comment: Thanks I think I’ll go with the multi tool

Comment: Yea multitool is probably a pretty good bet actually, not sure why I didn't think of that!

Answer (score 1):

I'd either do that old school with a hammer and chisel, or if I was feeling brave/foolhardy, with a circular saw with cut depth adjustment.

If you use a circular saw, check and set the cut depth to just minimally less than the depth of the stud that you're trimming, that way you can avoid damaging the wall and finish it off easily with a hammer/chisel.